Construct multi-modal network in ArcGIS Pro and setting the cost
I’m working on a multi-modal transportation network in ArcGIS Pro like the figure follow.
In my network, a trip involves walking to a bus stop, taking the bus, and walking again. The network consists of streets (walking), bus roads (bus routes), and bus connectors (segments that connect walking streets to bus roads).
In the travel cost setting, I try to set the waiting for bus time at the bus connectors but if I do this, there will be 2 waiting for bus time in a travel.
How can I determine if a bus connector is the first in a sequence of bus trips, and then apply the waiting time to only the first connector or whether there is another good method to set the waiting for bus time?
There is no GTFS dataset for this area.

